# How to create a non blocking socket without fcntl?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm working on a system that doesn't run unix / linux / windows or any familiar OS.
Yet, there are some libraries for sockets, one of them is socket.h.
The thing is that there is setsockopt function there, and some options, but there isn't fcntl.h library. I saw that this is the only way to get and set the socket's flags (O_NONBLOCK is what i seek).
Also, I saw that It is possible to use setsockopt with so_rcvtimeo and so_sndtimeo. I tried it and it is still blocking. The connect function was stuck when I was unplugging the ethernet cable right before the execution reached the connect line (in debug mode of course).
Is there a way to do it with the socket.h library only ?

Thanks,

**Edit:**
I'm using a system with Texas Instruments chip.
This is my current code, which doesn't work. "connect" returns -1 and I don't have errno to check what went wrong.

```
if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BLOCKING, (char *)&isBlockingOption, sizeof(isBlockingOption)) < 0) {
    /* closing the socket and exiting */
}
connect(s, &controlAddressStruct, sizeof(controlAddressStruct));
FD_ZERO(&conSocketSet);
FD_SET(s, &conSocketSet);
connectTimeout.tv_sec = 5;
connectTimeout.tv_usec = 0;
selectRet = fdselect( (int)s + 1, NULL, &conSocketSet, NULL, &connectTimeout);
if (selectRet == 1) {
   socketLen = sizeof(so_error);
   getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &so_error, &socketLen);
   if (so_error == 0) {
      return s;
   }
}
return INVALID_SOCKET;
```

now, when the ethernet cable is plugged between the two systems, so_error = 0 and s is returned. Then when I read the FTP server reply, I get error so I exit the program.
But, if I removed the setsockopt for the SO_BLOCKING, everything is fine and the FTP server sends me the requested file.

Comment: It would probably help if you specify your OS. Also so_rcvtimeo and so_sndtimeo are for the recv() and send() call, not connect().

Comment: Have a look at whether you can do it with ioctl().

Comment: Are you able to describe your OS in any fashion other than "not, not, not"?

Comment: It's a system with Texas Instruments chip.

Comment: Why are you using `SO_BLOCKING` if it is giving you problems?

Comment: isBlockOption is equal to 0 so the socket would not block. What other way can you offer ?

Answer (score 0):

If the `send()` and `recv()` interfaces are similar to the BSD sockets interface at all, the fourth parameter should correspond to flags. If so, you may be able to pass in `MSG_DONTWAIT` to the fourth parameter to effect non-blocking I/O.

Comment: I don't even reach the recv() section yet, the "connect" function returns -1 and I can't look at errno because it doesn't exist in my system.

Comment: You likely need to use `getsockopt()` with option `SO_ERROR` option to retrieve the error. But, I am only giving you what you should be able to find from online BSD socket API descriptions. I can't help you directly with particulars because I have no way to know how things work on your esoteric system.

Comment: As you can see in my editted question, I already tried it, and no error found when using getsockopt on SO_ERROR.

Comment: Your code doesn't check the return value of `connect()`. If `connect()` return -1, then immediate query `SO_ERROR` to see the error.